# Advanced Table Filtering In Excel Without VBA or Macros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to filter the data on this table to show rows with CC A, Program P2, and Low or Med Low Momentum.

[image: excel table]

| CC | Program | Name | ID | SMS OPT-in | Mobile | Email2 | End Date | Momentum | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | P1 | Name | 000000000 | FALSE |  | example@example.com | 1/2/2003 | Med High | Ahead |
| A | P2 | Name | 000000001 | FALSE |  | example@example.com | 1/3/2003 | High | Yes |
| A | P1 | Name | 000000002 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/4/2003 | Med | Yes |
| A | P1 | Name | 000000003 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/5/2003 | High | Yes |
| B | P1 | Name | 000000004 | FALSE |  | example@example.com | 1/6/2003 | High | Yes |
| A | P1 | Name | 000000005 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/7/2003 | Med Low | Behind |
| B | P1 | Name | 000000006 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/8/2003 | Med High | Ahead |
| A | P1 | Name | 000000007 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/9/2003 | Low | Behind |
| B | P1 | Name | 000000008 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/10/2003 | Low | Behind |
| B | P1 | Name | 000000009 | FALSE |  | example@example.com | 1/11/2003 | Low | Behind |
| A | P2 | Name | 000000010 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/12/2003 | Med | Behind |
| B | P2 | Name | 000000011 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/13/2003 | Med | Ahead |
| A | P1 | Name | 000000012 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/14/2003 | High | Yes |
| B | P1 | Name | 000000013 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/15/2003 | Med High | Ahead |
| B | P1 | Name | 000000014 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/16/2003 | High | Yes |
| B | P1 | Name | 000000015 | FALSE |  | example@example.com | 1/17/2003 | Med | Ahead |
| B | P1 | Name | 000000016 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/18/2003 | Med Low | Ahead |
| A | P1 | Name | 000000017 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/19/2003 | Low | Behind |
| A | P1 | Name | 000000018 | TRUE |  | example@example.com | 1/20/2003 | Med High | Ahead |

I figured out how to do this by creating a button with macros, but the spreadsheet cannot use macros as it's hosted on a domain site. How would one create something that can be clicked or activated within the sheet to only show the rows in the table that meet the criteria listed above?

I have not been able to find any resource to help with this goal. Not being able to use macros has limited my scope.

Comment: Use `FILTER()` function if you are using `MS365` or else use `INDEX()` with `AGGREGATE()` function. No clicking or activating but needs to enter formula in cells to fill down and fill right as per your requirements, if you are using `MS365` it will spill

Comment: You can use this formula: `=FILTER(A2:J20,(A2:A20="A")*(B2:B20="P2")*(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(I2:I20,{"Low","Med Low"}))),"NA")` for your present example it will return `NA` as there is no match with the given conditions. Also you can use `Advance Filter` option which is inbuilt in Excel but that will not be dynamic like formulas

Comment: You can use this formula as well: `=FILTER(A2:J20,(A2:A20="A")*(B2:B20="P2")*((I2:I20="Low")+(I2:I20="Med Low")),"NA")`